# View emails with Swing using javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, activation

I'm writing a mail client using javamail. I followed the example in javamail-samples folder but the CommandInfo is just null for all mails retrieved. As a way of debugging, I wrote the following code:

```
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);

    //get store object
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email", "password");

    System.out.println(store);

    //create folder
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message [] messages = inbox.getMessages();


    for(Message message: messages){            

        //message.
       DataHandler d = message.getDataHandler();

       CommandInfo in = d.getCommand("view");
       System.out.println(in);                
    }
```

The results:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
....
....
```

Anyone have an idea why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is finding the simple.mailcap file?  Usually it should be in the directory where you run the program.  Note that there's only a few viewers included with the program.  Are you trying to view a simple plain text message?